# collectionViewContentSize in iOS 10 using self-sizing cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, ios10

Prior to iOS 10, I had a self-sizing table view that solely consisted of a UICollectionView with self-sizing cells using a standard UICollectionViewFlowLayout.  The collection view cells are sized using auto-layout.  In order for the table cell to size itself correctly, I had to find the collection view's content size and use that within the table cell's systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:withHorizontalFittingPriority:verticalFittingPriority:.

I also found that the call to collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize used the estimatedItemSize instead of the correctly sized cell sizes unless I called collectionView layoutIfNeeded.  This resulted in a systemLayoutSizeFittingSize of:

```
- (CGSize) systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:(CGSize)targetSize withHorizontalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)horizontalFittingPriority verticalFittingPriority:(UILayoutPriority)verticalFittingPriority
{
    self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetSize.width, FLT_MAX);
    [self.collectionView layoutIfNeeded];

    CGSize collectionViewContentSize = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize;
    CGFloat verticalPadding = fabs(self.collectionViewTopPaddingConstraint.constant) + fabs(self.collectionViewBottomPaddingConstraint.constant);
    CGSize cellSize = CGSizeMake(collectionViewContentSize.width, collectionViewContentSize.height + verticalPadding);

    return cellSize;
}
```

The call to layoutIfNeeded now causes a `*** Assertion failure in -[_UIFlowLayoutSection computeLayoutInRect:forSection:invalidating:invalidationContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UIFlowLayoutSupport.m:823`

Am I violating some ethical rule by calling layoutIfNeeded within systemLayoutSizeFittingSize?  Is there some better method to calculate a collection view's content size when it is using self-sizing cells?  I would rather not have to move from auto layout to doing these size calculations in code, but that is certainly a worst case option.

Answer (score 17):

This is some strange bug in iOS10 with iPhone Plus devices only. I've faced the same issue, my solution was to call `layoutIfNeeded` like this:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    collectionView.layoutIfNeeded() // Patch: only to solve UIKit crash on Plus models
    return 1
}
```

Doing the same thing in different UICollectionViewDataSources methods will work as well

Comment: holy goodness, I would have been `head() -> Desk`.  I don't want to know how you stumbled upon this.

Comment: The weirdest bug i ever encountered, i had production crashes like crazy...

Comment: @user924 as i said "Doing the same thing in different UICollectionViewDataSources methods will work as well" try it.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue when develop my app on iOS 10. Remove the first line solved my problem.

`self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, targetSize.width, FLT_MAX); //Remove this`

Hope this help!

Comment: Without setting the frame to be an appropriate width, the layout size is miscalculated.  It doesn't crash, but the size is totally wrong.  I ended up replacing my collection views with a custom grid UIView subclass, since the layout calculations were relatively simple, and self-sizing collection views are somewhere between fragile and unusable.

Comment: Did you try to call `[self.collectionView.superView layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: That causes a different assertion failure in collection view.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, calling `invalidateLayout` before layout is a workaround for this issue.

In a `UIViewController` subclass:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

or in a `UIView` subclass:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: this causes a layout feedback loop

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue when develop my app on iOS 10 and set `UICollectionViewDataSource` to itself on `awakeFromNib`,like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    // set your layout 
    collectionViewLayout = layout
    // set dataSource equal to self in here cause a crash
    dataSource = self
}
```

then I move the `UICollectionViewDataSource` setting code to `layoutSubviews`,the problem solved,like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        dataSource = self
    }

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    // set your layout 
    collectionViewLayout = layout
    // set dataSource equal to self in here cause a crash
    dataSource = self
}
```

Hope this help!